# Is this movl instruction necessary?

Tags: c, assembly

I read the textbook "Computer Systems A programmer's perspective". It gives an example program:

```
/* read input line and write it back */
void echo(){
  char buf[8]; /* way too small !*/
  gets(buf);
  puts(buf);
}
```

The assembly code for this is:

```
1  echo:
2   pushl %ebp
3   movl  %esp, %ebp
4   pushl %ebx
5   subl  $20, %esp
6   leal  -12(%ebp), %ebx
7   movl  %ebx, (%esp)
8   call  gets
9   movl  %ebx, (%esp)        // This does not look useful for me
10  call  puts  
11  addl  $20, %esp
12  popl  %ebx
13  popl  %ebp
14  ret
```

Line 9 seems useless here since line 7 has already store buf at the top of the stack. Then it calls gets. When gets return, buf will be at the top of the stack.

My question is:
Is line 9 useless here?

EDIT: This is Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is: Is line 9 useless here?

No. You cannot assume that `gets` will not change the value on the stack. It is its argument and it is allowed to modify it.

`%ebx` on the other hand [is callee-save](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl). The `gets` function has to preserve it.

Comment: That is, `gets` may look like `*(arg++) = readChar()` or similar, right?

Comment: Same would apply to interrupts in non-protected modes and instrumentation code placed in function headers/footers.

Comment: Even if gets changes the values on the stack (assume there is no buffer overflow here), in what case this will matter? could you elaborate? I mean before I call gets, %esp is pointing to buf. Then I call gets to establish a new stack frame. When gets return, we get back to the old stack frame. And %esp is still pointing to buf which is the bottom of the stack in echo().

Comment: @dannycrane Well of course `gets` is allowed to change the stack slot that contains its arguments but not to do a buffer overflow. There is no such thing as a “stack frame”: there is only a stack pointer registers and a piece of memory. `gets` is allowed to get its arguments by using an offset from `%esp` that goes beyond its stack frame, and it has to do so for reading, and it is also allowed to write to the same location because the copy of the argument on the stack effectively belongs to it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, gets will change the content in the buf, but it will not change the address of the buf...could you give a detailed hypothetical example how the %esp will not return to buf after gets returns? I failed to understand the explanation because I assume gets is doing what it is supposed to do rather than a generic function (which your explanation seems to suggest.)

Comment: @dannycrane If you want your assembly programs to work, you write them so that they will keep working in interaction with any functions outside your control that respect the rules, not just with functions written as you imagine these functions ought to be written. In fact this principle is not limited to assembly. If you want to be sure that `gets` does not modify that part of the stack, the only way is to write your own `gets`.

Comment: @dannycrane I wouldn't expect a competent book with “computer systems” in the title to do otherwise, for the same reason that books about building bridges do not say “if the bridge does not lead to a dairy, then there is no reason for a milk truck to go other it. We therefore assume that all vehicles going over the bridge will weight no more than a car.”

Answer (score 0):

when you are calling the gets function, it may happen that it  can  modify the values of arguments(%ebx in your case).  since you have not mentioned the other part of your code, can't say about that..but its good to store the buff into stack top again,after a function call..